# "Unable to get property 'getData' of undefined or null reference" in IE but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, excel, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Thanks to the help of another member I have successfully implemented a JS method that has the ability to paste excel data and split it into an HTML textbox table form ([see thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572607/adding-the-ability-to-paste-excel-data-into-django-form)).

The issue that I am now faced with is that this is only functional in Chrome, while IE10 and IE11 both flag the following error:

**"Unable to get property 'getData' of undefined or null reference."**

This error is thrown in the 2nd line of the function (below):

```
function (event) {
    var input_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var value = event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'); //ERROR in IE
    /* ... */
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the original paste
}
```

Wondering if anyone can see the issue at hand with why Chrome is satisfied while IE is not.

Comment: This question actually solved my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035071/intercept-paste-event-in-javascript

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer found here: [Intercept paste event in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035071/intercept-paste-event-in-javascript)

This worked for me.

```
if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) { // IE
    pastedText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
}
else if (event.originalEvent.clipboardData && event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData) { // other browsers
    pastedText = event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
}
```

Comment: This actually is the correct answer for this question, thanks pj2452, it looks like the clipboardData from the event handler comes as null for internet explorer.

Answer (score 2):

[In IE, it should be](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536436(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
var value = event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData("Text");
```

Comment: Thank you. Will this work in Chrome? Wondering how I can have it function for both browsers.

Comment: You can try adding a browser check validation if not

Comment: Sorry, but how would I do that?

Comment: You can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411551/if-browser-is-internet-explorer-run-an-alternative-script-instead

Comment: So as it turns out, I modified 'text/plain' to 'Text' and I am still getting the same error in IE...

Comment: Although this method works for chrome, it doesn't work for internet explorer which is the main question here.

Comment: This is incorrect, this will fail in internet explorer and work in chrome only. See the accepted answer.